# Dynamic c++ Library in Python - can't find dylib file

Tags: python, c++, cmake, ctypes, dynamic-library

I am trying to import a c++ function for use in Python(3.9) on MacOS. My project has the following structure,

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cmake-build-debug
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── Testing
│   ├── build.ninja
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   └── libDENCLUS.dylib
├── denclus.py
├── library.cpp
└── library.h
```

with CMakeLists.txt as,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(DENCLUS)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(DENCLUS SHARED library.cpp)
```

the header file,

```
#ifndef DENCLUS_LIBRARY_H
#define DENCLUS_LIBRARY_H

extern "C" void hello();

#endif //DENCLUS_LIBRARY_H
```

the source file,

```
#include "library.h"

#include <iostream>

void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

and the python file,

```
from ctypes.util import find_library
import ctypes
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
lib = f'{cwd}/cmake-build-debug/libDENCLUS.dylib'
if find_library(lib):
    libx = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib)
    libx.hello()
else:
    raise OSError("Could not find lib.")
```

ctypes `find_library` returns `None` and the subsequent block which calls the function `hello` is not executed if i specify the absolute path to the `.dylib` file, or if I call it as `find_library(DENCLUS)` or any similar permutation. How can I get my python code to find the library and call the function?

EDIT:

I can call the c++ function outside of the if block. I think there is an issue with `find_library` on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

According to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - Finding shared libraries](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries) (**emphasis** is mine):

> ctypes.util.**find_library**(*name*)
>
> Try to find a library and return a pathname. ***name* is the library name without any prefix like *lib*, suffix like `.so`, `.dylib` or version number** (this is the form used for the posix linker option *-l*). If no library can be found, returns `None`.

That's why *find_library* returns *None*.

The same resource also states (although I don't necessarily agree with):

> If wrapping a shared library with [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes), it *may* be better to determine the shared library name at development time, and hardcode that into the wrapper module instead of using *find_library()* to locate the library at runtime.

The million dollar question: **if the path of the library is already known, why the need of calling *find_library***? It makes no sense, as it simply beats its purpose.

Simply use:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import os


cwd = os.getcwd()
lib_path = f"{cwd}/cmake-build-debug/libDENCLUS.dylib"
lib = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
hello = lib.hello
# @TODO: !!! Define argtypes ans restype for any function called via CTypes !!!
hello.argtypes = ()
hello.restype = None
hello()
```

Regarding the *@TODO* (even if for this particular case it's not necessary), check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

If for some reason (that remains unknown to me at this point), you feel the urge to use *find_library*, here's how to do it:

```py
os.environ["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = os.pathsep.join((os.environ.get("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH", ""), os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "cmake-build-debug")))
lib_path = ct.util.find_library("DENCLUS")
# ...
```