# Add directory to PATH inside a Python script such that a third-party module can find a DLL with ctypes find_library

Tags: python, path, ctypes, pythonpath

Let's say a third-party module `moduleXYZ.py` (that I don't want to fork/modify) does:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
find_library("gsdll64.dll")
```

In my code `main.py` I'm importing it with

```
import moduleXYZ
```

This DLL is in `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin` which is not in my global system path.

Question: **how to add this directory to the path (for the duration of the script run, not permanently for the system) *from inside my script* `main.py` such that find_library will succeed?**

I tried:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ';C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin'
sys.path += ['C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin']
import mymoduleXYZ
```

but it still fails.

Note:

- my script is always run with `python main.py`, and I don't want to have to add this directory to path from a batch file or from terminal or from command-line: all this should be done inside the main.py script itself.
- I've always read [Permanently adding a file path to sys.path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257747/permanently-adding-a-file-path-to-sys-path-in-python), [How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages), and similar questions but this doesn't apply here
- I don't want to add this directory permanently to the system PATH
- a general solution to add a directory to path for the currently ran script would be interesting, if possible not specific to ctypes/DLL but to everything using path in general

---

Edit: [`os.add_dll_directory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) looked promising but it doesn't work here:

```
import os
from ctypes.util import find_library 
os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin')
find_library(r'gsdll64.dll')  # None.........

find_library(r'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin')  # working
```

Comment: Have you tried `import sys` `sys.path.append("the path to the folder")`?

Comment: @user3808430 No it doesn't work (I just tried), also this is similar to `sys.path += ['/path/to']`.

Comment: `+=` creates a new list in memory, whereas append updates the old one, so I figured it was possible that it could have a different effect. But yeah I'm a bit stumped :/

Comment: I think  is.add_dll_directory should do the trick for more or less current python versions, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory

Comment: Thanks @ead. This will probably work for ctypes' `find_library`, but more generally, how to add something to the path for the currently-ran script? (without export to environment variable outside the python script)

Comment: @ead Strangely it doesn't work: `import os; os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin'); from ctypes.util import find_library; print(find_library('gsdll64.dll'))` but this DLL file is present in this folder. (See edit in my answer)

Comment: [\[SO\]: Dynamic c++ Library in Python - can't find dylib file (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73077158/4788546), [\[SO\]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/4788546). *sys.path* has nothing to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, this was a noob mistake: I forgot to escape the string which contains `\b` with `r'...'`.
This works:

`main.py`

```
import os, sys
os.environ['PATH'] += r';C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin'
import moduleXYZ
```

`moduleXYZ.py`

```
from ctypes.util import find_library 
print(find_library(r'gsdll64.dll'))
```

But a more general answer that would change the system path for the currently being-ran script, from the script itself would still be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have same code in my project, worked in 3.8 and 3.9
, not work in 3.10.0 and 3.10.7

```
import os
from ctypes.util import find_library 
os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin')
find_library(r'gsdll64.dll')
```